# How do I calculate the total difference between two columns of figures in Google spreadsheet/Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-docs

Usually I would just calculate the difference of each row like this: `=B1-A1`

Then I would sum up the values of the column like this `=SUM(C1:C10)` and get my desired value.

I don't want the C-column.  Is it possible to calculate it immediately?

For example I tried: `=SUM((B1-A1):(B10-A10))` (which doesn't work)

Usually I can find the answers somewhere in the documentation, but my Math-English vocabulary is a little bit rusty and with German documentation I haven't found what I was looking for.

I know I could put 10 values manually inside the sum.  But this doesn't scale gracefully, I want to be able to change only a few values in the formula instead of adding 1000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work for this case:

```
=SUM(B1:B10) - SUM(A1:A10)
```

Comment: Actually i tried it with date but ended up with a weird value. But when i think about it it makes sense (*hit brick on my head*). Changed it to hours and the value is correct now. Do you know, how to do it with date format?

Comment: How can I ensure this number is always positive? I want to calculate how far off from an estimate we were... either positive or negative.

Comment: @ATSiem: It's probably long past useful, but the ABS() function ought to help.

Comment: How can you get the differences of textual columns? Etc Column A: A, B, C. Column B: A, B, B.

Comment: This would not work in cases of missing values - say A3 is missing, the difference `A3-B3` should be missing too, and not be used in the total difference calculation. But using the above calculation the result would include row 3 with the value of `0 - B3`. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @eli-k The answer below using SUMPRODUCT works for that situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate each value in turn, evaluate it as a positive number, THEN work out what that adds to then your best bet is an array formula.
These are entered not by pressing ENTER at the end, but CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. When done, you will notice a pair of braces on either side ( `{ }` ).
Note - you must use this method, you cannot type the braces and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER etc in

```
=sum ( abs(b1:b10 - a1:a10) )
```

Clearly, you can replace sum with average if that better suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Sheets**

If any of the cells might be empty, other threads suggest SumProduct. E.g.

=SumProduct(--(b1:b10<>""), (b1:b10 - a1:a10))

The first argument provides an array of TRUE/FALSE of whether the value in the B range is empty then uses `--` to convert those booleans to 1s or 0s.

The other argument is the desired difference.

SumProduct then multiplies those two arrays resulting in the total difference between the two columns excluding the missing values in the B range.

**Excel**

Excel 2010 threw a #VALUE! error against that 2nd argument. An alternative would be:

=(Sum(b1:b10)-SumProduct(--(b1:b10<>""),a1:a10))/Count(b1:b10)

The only caveat to this approach is that if all the cells in the B range are empty, it will result in #DIV/0!.